# Login callback in meteor app with facebook connect

Tags: facebook, node.js, meteor

How can i subscribe a callback to Meteor.loginWithFacebook() or Meteor.loginWithGoogle()  methods?  In case there is not such thing, What would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just added callback in their last *auth* commit: [69110dec0f90877a9294057a4572876d0dae37e0](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/69110dec0f90877a9294057a4572876d0dae37e0)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine it's the same with facebook (note code is coffeescript)

```
Meteor.loginWithGithub = _.wrap(Meteor.loginWithGithub, function(login, options, callback) 
  {

    // Create a new callback 
    newCallback = function()
    {
      callback();
      console.log('custom stuff can go here');
    }

    // Call the original login with new wrapping callback
    login(options, newCallback);
  }
);
```

Comment: Fair enough. :P Also _.wrap is a cool function so thanks for pointing it out. If you edit the answer I can upvote it.

Comment: Upvoted and sorry about my initial grumpy statement. Coffeescript is cool. :P

Answer (score 0):

Although meteor dont provide that, they are working hard to get it into the next release, check out their auth branch on github